# UIBarButtonItem Title Change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following UIBarButton Item:

```
  UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 45.0f, 30.0f)];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    backButton.titleLabel.text = @"Back";
    backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"texgyreadventor-regular.otf" size:20.0f];
    backButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    _backItem = backItem;
```

In some other method, I set it to be on the navigation bar as follows:

`[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_backItem];`

So far, everything works as expected. But right before I add it on the navigation bar on top, I would like to change its text. Here's one the things I tried doing:

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"NEW TITLE";`

This however, does not work. How can I add a title during runtime on the fly?

Comment: @Legolas This needs a `drawRect` method... So what are you talking about?

Comment: Another solution is that you can take an NSMutableString globally (Class Level). Put 'Back' in string and pass to button label and just before adding change the string replace string with 'New Title'.

Comment: @KhalidUsman its not a race against inefficiency.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
 [button setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The state has to be defined.

Comment: you should accept "Paul de Lange" answer since he gave you this answer :)

Comment: It doesn't work though. What he is doing is retrieving that button and assigning it to a button, changing the title and never setting it back. I will edit his answer and mark it as right.

Comment: Thanks Omar! Nayefc, you don't have to set it back, I just retrieve the pointer to the button and then change the title property of the object at that address. BTW: I didn't know you could accept your own answers, now I understand why some people can have such big reputations for no apparent reason.

Comment: Paul no it did not work. Unless you set the pointer to be a weak pointer, it will not work. It makes sense. And I also tested it. I edited your answer and wanted to mark it as correct but you reverted the change and -1'ed me, so I guess I won't. :)

Comment: Paul, I tested it too. So I can guarantee it does not work. Let me explain some theory though: `button` does not point to the bar button item in the navigation bar as you would think. By default, it will retain a new object by definition of ARC. To make it behave the way you want it to, you must specify `__weak` on it. Furthermore, `UIButton`s need to match a title with a state. This answer has been backed by an Apple Engineer at WWDC - I had someone I know there ask how buttons and their titles work last week.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the button again using:

```
UIView* view = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView;
UIButton* button = (UIButton*)view;
[button setTitle: @"NEW TITLE" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Are you starting iOS Nayefc, I see you have a lot of questions these last few days :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking (like me just now), in newer versions of iOS the accepted answer no longer works. It has become barButton.title, which is a read-write `String?` (in Swift) or `NSString`(in Obj-C).

Answer (score -4):

Instead of

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"NEW TITLE";
```

use

```
UIButton *backButton = (UIButton *)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView;
backButton.titleLabel.text = @"changed";
```

**UPDATE**:
If you want to change the title before adding it on the nav bar do the following

```
UIButton *backButton = (UIButton *)_backItem.customView;
backButton.titleLabel.text = @"changed";
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because it would change `backButton`'s title, which is not on the navbar.

Comment: @Nayefc, yes am from amman, and what exactly you want to change, from your question it seems that you wanted to change the title of the button you added? please explain more

Comment: just that. Its not changing what so ever.

Comment: that is very strange there must be something wrong you are doing

Comment: @Nayefc post what is your problem, what are the steps you do, please use clear language to explain what are you trying to achieve and what is your problem :)

Comment: this is as clear as possible. I even have code up there. I fixed it. See my answer above.

Comment: This doesn't work - you need to use @paul-de-lange's method above and call `setTitle`